# "Attempted relative import with no known parent package" strikes again

Tags: python

I'm yet another user who struggles with Python's imports.
This is my project structure:

```
Project/
|-- __init__.py
|-- utils/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- utils.py
|
|-- app/
|   |-- main.py
```

**main.py:**

```py
from .utils import utils
```

which results in an error: "*ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package*".

Adding on top of the main.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

fixes the problem but I mean...

why are imports so confusing in python lol?

I also tried: `from utils import utils`, but: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'".

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute import, you have to specifies the full path of the imported module or package, so for your `main.py` it will be:

```
# main.py
from utils import utils
```

If that dont work check that the parent directory of Project is in your Python path, you can do it temporarily with `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/parent_directory_of_Project` You also have other option like converting your project to a package but absolute import is generally the best.